# Pygame won't print text in certain circumstances

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to print "you lose" to the screen when the user moves a box off the playable screen, however this doesn't seem to work unless I call it from outside my main while loop. I have defined a function to handle the creation of the text, the rendering and 'blit'ing of it, although this has no effect when it is called from inside the while loop however it does when it is called from outside it at the bottom. I have checked and the function is executed from both locations, though it only seems to work from one.

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()

red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gamewidth = 900
gameheight = 900
snakecolour = black
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((gamewidth,gameheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

gameExit = False
boxDimensions = 10
lead_x = (gamewidth // 2) - ((gamewidth // 2) % 20)
lead_y = (gameheight // 2) - ((gameheight // 2) % 20)
lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
def message_to_screen(msg, color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [gamewidth//2, gameheight//2])


while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if not (lead_x_change == boxDimensions):
                    lead_x_change = -boxDimensions
                    lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if not (lead_x_change == -boxDimensions):
                    lead_x_change = boxDimensions
                    lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if not (lead_y_change == boxDimensions):
                    lead_y_change = -boxDimensions
                    lead_x_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if not (lead_y_change == -boxDimensions):
                    lead_y_change = boxDimensions
                    lead_x_change = 0


    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change

    if lead_x > gamewidth or lead_x < 0 or lead_y > gameheight or lead_y < 0:
        snakecolour = red
        gameExit = True
        message_to_screen("You Lose!", red)
        pygame.display.update()
        #message_to_screen("You Lose!", red) WONT WORK HERE

    if lead_x > gamewidth:
        lead_x = gamewidth - boxDimensions
        lead_x_change = 0
    elif lead_x < 0:
        lead_x = 0
        lead_x_change = 0
    elif lead_y > gameheight:
        lead_y = gameheight - boxDimensions
    elif lead_y < 0:
        lead_y = 0
        lead_y_change = 0
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, snakecolour, [lead_x,lead_y,boxDimensions,boxDimensions])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(15)
#message_to_screen("You Lose!", red) DOES WORK HERE
#pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(3)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It's rather strange, I hope someone knows the root of this issue.

Comment: Could you write end of the game, "you lose" ? On the pygame screen, not IDLE or CMD.Also after _lead_x_ part, put them into _while_ loop please

Comment: can you fix your indentation

Comment: Have you tried calling `display.update` immediately after the message? Looks like you are filling the display before the next update call?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Sorry, I've fixed that now

Comment: @AirThomas Yes, I tried putting the update both in the function itself, and just after the function was called, it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Indent properly, I can't even run the code.

Comment: @Igor sorry, should be fixed now

Comment: @user3537381, your code does work you just need a `time.sleep` after a `pygame.display.update()`  in the while loop

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thankyou, that does seem to work. Although it still doesn't explain  why if I just put 'message_to_screen("You Lose!", red)' in the while loop outside of that if statement it doesn't work. Because that should render it every frame, right?

Comment: no you call update later in your code so the display is updated and you never get to see the text, the sleep is what allows you to see the text

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But surely the text is only shown on the screen when update is called

Comment: yes but you don't call update in that if statement and when it gets called later you are leaving the game loop as `gameExit = True`, I also would just `break` instead of the call to sleep so the text stays on the screen until it closes otherwise you hit the later update before you leave the loop

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I figured it out, it was because gameDisplay.fill(white) would clear any text on the screen if it was called after the call to draw text.

Comment: Yes, that is my point you are updating the display, I would use this code http://pastebin.com/GGqCqwhh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message_to_screen("YOU LOSE!",(255,0,0))
pygame.display.update()
sleep(3)
```

> From **AirThomas** comment, this is working. Outside of the while loop, put this statement.
>
> For score board:

```
text = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 30)
score=0
text1=text.render("{}".format(score), True,(255,255,255))
while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    #codes
    #codes
    #codes
    if sneakeatssomething:
        score += 1
        text1=text.render("{}".format(score), True,(255,255,255)) #rendering the score again
    #codes
    #codes 
    screen.blit(text1,(275,6))#showing the score
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(150)
```

This is updating the score when sneak eats and printing it to the pygame screen

Comment: This does work, but it still doesn't answer the question of why doesn't this work inside the while loop?

Comment: Well, I dont know either. I just solve your and my problem with @AirThomas's tricky help :-)

Comment: But what  if you wanted to have a score board or something that continually updated, you wouldn't be able to do that by having the call statement outside the while loop

Comment: @user3537381 check my answer again

Comment: If this solved your question, please check it as answer.